# Keep a local copy of nfs mount

Tags: filesystems, nfs, synchronization

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17216/keep-local-copy-of-nfs-mount-on-computer) was asked 9 years ago but did not receive an answer for what was asked, only suggestion for alternatives (which now seem outdated).

I want the ability to cache selected files / directories on my laptop for offline use, and when I go back online the changes I make on the laptop should be merged to the NFS server. The NFS server is more like a backup server, all changes happen on my laptop and then are synced to it so

1. I can then remove it from my laptop to free up space, re-download later
2. Server has read-access to files and it can run some scripts on them

I understand that in a very very general setting you run into issues like merge conflicts, but that's going to happen only rarely in my case, so it's acceptable if I'm manually prompted and asked which version of the file to keep. And I need a low-resource way of doing this on a laptop -- without constant file watcher or connection watcher when I'm on battery power, so I suppose the option of both manual (when on battery) and automated (when plugged in) sync would be the best.

I don't think this is a very unique requirement, several people must be looking for similar solutions, and I'm wondering what ways exist to satisfy this.

Answer (score 0):

With `rsync` you could that in no time, with a couple of scripts. You could spot merge problems, for example, by using `--dry-run`, though in your situation it seems that `--newer` could probably do it.

If `/mnt/nfs` is your NFS mount, then you'd always use `/mnt/my_local_nfs` and sync back and forth when you know you are online. **You** decide how often to run `rsync` and whether to do it manually or automatically/periodically. The scripts would have to have a check around them to see if the mount is online.