# autofs mount local directory when nfs unavailable

Tags: nfs, automounting, autofs, bind-mount, freeipa

I want to have my home directory be an NFS mount when it's available, or a local directory when it's not.  Think of a laptop that I might want to take somewhere off of my normal network.  What I have today is an automount map that mounts an NFS share on my home.  I've been poking around stack exchange and it suggests coda [Keep local copy of nfs mount on computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17216/keep-local-copy-of-nfs-mount-on-computer) However it's a really old project and I'm not seeing it in the apt repository leading me to believe this is probably not going to work well.

What I've tried to do is automount nfs home directories into /nethome like this:

```bsh
/etc/auto.nethome * -fstype=nfs4,rw,sec=sys,soft,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,no_root_squash h2gt2g.deepthot.aa:/volume1/homes/&

mkdir -p /nethome/me

/etc/fstab:  /home/me /nethome/me none defaults,bind 0,0
```

Sadly this doesn't work at all.  Either it ends up with the bind or nothing working at all.  I'm thinking I can't do something this simple minded.

Has anyone else succeeded at doing something like this?  It seems like this would be something people would do.

As a side note, I've had nfs automounted home directories on all my machines/vms for 20 or so years.  I've been wanting to do something similar to what I just described almost as long, but have never had any luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to keep "network home" and "real home" as two separate entities on your laptop.
Then put in a .profile (which is in your real home) a script like

```
if [ -e /nethome/me/.profile ]; then
    HOME=/nethome/me/
    cd $HOME
    . ./.profile
    exec bash
fi
```

Basically you would still have your local 'real' home, but in case the network one is available - it would be used as a new home.
This way you can even create several homes for different networks.

But I would still suggest to not play with a $HOME, but create for yourself a set of aliases for all network related (and not) folders and set these aliases depending on where the actual directory is in that particular network.
Something like:

```
if [ -d /mynas/projects/projectA ]; then
   projectA=/mynas/projects/projectA
elif [ -d /company/group/somelegacygarbage/projectA ]; then
   projectA=/company/group/somelegacygarbage/projectA
else 
   projectA=/home/me/projects/projectA
fi
```

It would be easier later to just type `cd $projectA` and it would immediately bring you to the most relevant directory.

Comment: I'm going to need to think on this.  I kinda glossed over some of the complexities (LDAP, kerberos, and so on) which made this solution not come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I manage a bunch of computers that have network homedirs (AFS, which is similar to Coda, from the same university), and due to limitations in sssd, I use the automount system to dynamically mount a home directory to the network path *or* a local directory if the network isn’t available. (Actually, more complex, it also tries a cifs automount dir)

Basically, automount can use a program instead of a direct mount definition.  For example:

```
   /home  program:/etc/auto.home
```

And then the output of that program (/etc/auto.home) should look like either your NFS mount definition in your question, *or* a bind mount to a local dir, depending on whatever shell logic you decide.